# How to configurate Ehcache for peer-to-peer replication

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, p2p, distributed-caching

I read a few times that ehcache can be used in replication mode. So I can set up a cluster without a terracotta-server (like a peer-to-peer network). But I only find information about the replication in old ehcache docs (version 2.x). In the new documentation the point "Replicated Cache" is missing and the ehcache-config is incompatible with the new ehcache version. Is this feature in v3.x gone ? If not: how to config ehcache ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

This feature has not been ported in Ehcache 3.x indeed.

It suffers from a total lack of consistency since it can only offer *last write wins* on a *per node* basis which is rarely an acceptable guarantee.

If you need to share a single cache across multiple nodes, the Terracotta clustering is the recommended way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)